# Creating a new column based on duplicates from another column

Tags: python

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| Contract_ID | Agreement_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 05/04/1997 |
| 1 | 03/02/1997 |
| 2 | 05/08/2020 |
| 2 | 08/07/2020 |
| 3 | 05/07/2020 |
| 3 | 09/08/2020 |

I would like to create a new Agreement_Date_x column populated by the Agreement_Date from the duplicated Contract_ID. In summary, I would like an output like this:

| Contract_ID | Agreement_Date | Agreement_Date_x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05/04/1997 | 03/02/1997 |
| 2 | 05/08/2020 | 08/07/2020 |
| 3 | 05/07/2020 | 09/08/2020 |

This is not show-cased in my example, but some Contract_IDs have 3+ duplicates (all with different Agreement_Dates). I would like to create a separate column for each duplicate.

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can add a helper column and `pivot`:

```
(df
 .assign(col=df.groupby('Contract_ID').cumcount().add(1))
 .pivot(index='Contract_ID', columns='col', values='Agreement_Date')
 .add_prefix('Agreement_Date_')
 .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
   Contract_ID Agreement_Date_1 Agreement_Date_2
0            1       05/04/1997       03/02/1997
1            2       05/08/2020       08/07/2020
2            3       05/07/2020       09/08/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = df.groupby('Contract_ID')['Agreement_Date']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(a.apply(list)))
df2['Contract_ID'] = a.groups.keys()
```